How do I access the development tools and change the defaultOption?
I would like to know if there is any way to change the default state of an ECHARTS chart with developer tools. For example, it would be something like:


        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

            // Access type:'gauge' defaultOption
            echarts.extendSeriesModel({
                type: 'gauge',
                defaultOption: {
                    startAngle: 180,
                    endAngle: 0,
                    radius: '75%',
                    axisLine: {
                        lineStyle: {
                            color: [[1, "#333"]]
                        }
                    },
                    itemStyle: {
                        color: '#f00'
                    }
                }
            });

            // init
            const chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart'));

            // option
            const option = {
                series: [
                    {
                        type: 'gauge', // new defaultOption (does not work)
                        data: [{ value: 50, name: 'Speed' }]
                    }
                ]
            };

            // setOption
            chart.setOption(option);
        });
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.5.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <title>Custom Gauge</title>
</head>

<div id="chart" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"></div>



My intention (which is certainly incorrect) is to access the type of a chart internally (e.g. type:'gauge') and change its default settings for each type:'gauge' created.
Note that I prefer to use something related to these methods.
EDIT
When processing this code:
        // option
        const option = {
            series: [
                {
                    type: 'gauge', // new defaultOption (does not work)
                    data: [{ value: 50, name: 'Speed' }]
                }
            ]
        };

        // setOption
        chart.setOption(option);

The result would be:

In other words, I'd like to change the initial pattern of the graph, but using an ECHARTS function/method designed for this purpose (see link above).

Can you elaborate a bit on what you want the final result to look like?

@KostasMinaidis I've edited the question. Thanks for commenting.
